# How to set global node modules so that all application can use same

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to node, i have made few small application using node, but everytime i have to use `npm install` for every application which download the required dependencies in `node_modules` folder. There are many libraries which are common.

I tried installing using `npm install express -g` but i was not sure how to use this dependency in other application which is in some other folder.

Is there any way i can have only one folder like in `D:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` from where my all applications can have the module which they need ?

Can anyone let me know how to do the settings for the same ?

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every node application that has a `package.json` has a specific set of rules for using specific versions of it's modules. You can install globally only one version of a specific module, but if you happen to have an application that needs an older / newer version that is not installed globally on your dev environment, then it will fail to work.

The recommended way of using node modules ( packages ) is to have a local directory inside your project, which contains **all** libraries that the project needs. This practice is everywhere and so you should follow it.

There are some ways to mitigate the slow `npm install`, though.

There is a new `npm`-replacement, created and maintained by Facebook, called [`yarn`](http://yarnpkg.com).

What `yarn` does is it creates a local cache of all installed packages and then symlinks them to your project folder from your local computer cache. This way the `npm install` procedure becomes very fast.

Comment: ok, i can't use yarn rgt now, but i can use latest version of modules for all my small apps for now, how to proceed then?

Comment: How to set proxy with yarn??

Comment: You can add proxy with `yarn --proxy` or `yarn --https-proxy` argument. Otherwise you can just put it inside your `.yarnrc` or `.npmrc` same way as you would declare it with npm